# How to change tqdm.notebook progress bar style?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, progress-bar, tqdm

I am using tqdm in a notebook (run within VS Code).
I am importing tqdm with

```
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm
```

The bar Looks like this
[image]

But I'd like to have a normal progress bar made with ASCII characters like this
[image]

Do you know if it is possible to change the bar style?

#### Edit

I know there is `bar_format` parameter in `tqdm()` but I don't know how to change it to make my bar being printed with ASCII characters

Answer (score 0):

If your question is "How can I switch automatically between terminal and notebook style", the answer is: Use this

```
from tqdm.autonotebook import tqdm
```

If your question is "Can I customize the tqdm bar style", the answer is: Yes, you can take complete control over the style, see `help(tqdm.tqdm)` for all the defaults that can be reset.